# Ember set belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with a belongsTo relationShip:

```
Gmcontrolpanel.Offer = DS.Model.extend({
shop: DS.belongsTo('shop')
});
```

When I try to save it, it says that i have to set a shop record to the shop attribute;
but i don't load the shop record in this route; i have all shop's properties saved in localStorage, so it would be a waste to load the shop with a find in the model hook; how can I set the shop's id (that is in localStorage.shopId) to the shop's attribute of the offer record that I'm creating?